# Can I perform only instance segmentation with Mask R-CNN?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks

I've to do instance segmentation of microscopy images. I was reading the [Mask R-CNN paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1703.06870) and found that it has an additional branch for predicting mask and that it predicts class, bounding box and mask parallelly. Now I don't have bounding boxes in the training data, can I still use Mask R-CNN for just instance segmentation?

This is the multi task loss on each RoI they used during training $L=L_{cls}+L_{box}+L_{mask}$, so I don't think it's possible.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: you can obtain box from instance masks

Comment: @shimao are you saying obtaining masks from training data using it's masks which are given? I'll try that
But can Mask R-CNN find masks with 'just' segmentation in the training data and not generating boxes?

Comment: I thought the bounding boxes (sizes) are selected by engineers by clustering, like k-means. It depends on the sizes of objects in your project.

Comment: that would be the *anchor boxes* @LernerZhang -- they're chosen to match well with the typical sizes of bounding boxes.

Comment: @shimao Oh, but it seems that they are almost equivalent. Maybe I made a mistake, but please see this article [Anchor Boxes for Object Detection](https://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/ug/anchor-boxes-for-object-detection.html) which says that *Anchor boxes are a set of predefined bounding boxes of a certain height and width.*